# Why does opening the access code window last minutes?

Tags: ms-access

After the start of Access (2016, 2019, 365) the first opening of the code window (ALT-F11) lasts very long depending on the amount of objects / code inside the project indepentendly if its an Access- or SQL-Server-database. With older Access versions (2000, 2003) there wasn't such a problem. The process takes 1-2 minutes.

Did anyone else encounter the problem and came up with a solution?

Comment: Do you have any Add-Ins in the VBE? If yes, try disabling them one by one.

Comment: @Andre No, not a single Add-In.

Comment: Seems VBE opens all modules by default. Perhaps this was a change after 2003 with accdb platform. I don't see any way to turn this off.